# How is a non-static method accessed without an object?

Tags: javafx-8, non-static

I am new to JavaFX. In my following code, `getHBox()` is a non-static method is accessed without creating an object.

```
public class Main extends Application { 
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

        //Main m = new Main();

        try {
            BorderPane rootPane = new BorderPane();

            rootPane.setTop(getHBox());
            //rootPane.setTop(m.getHBox());

            Scene scene = new Scene(rootPane,400,400);
            scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("application.css").toExternalForm());
            primaryStage.setScene(scene);
            primaryStage.show();
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public HBox getHBox()
    {
        HBox hb = new HBox(15);
        hb.getChildren().add(new Button("Press"));
        return hb;
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Now I have looked at the answers in Stackoverflow. Guys are talking something about class member. How is `getHBox()` method different from any other method? Please provide some explanation or direct me to an appropriate tutorial.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> In my following code, `getHBox()` is a non-static method is accessed without creating an object.

That is incorrect.  As used in the code presented, `getHBox()` is invoked only by `start()`, another non-static method.  As an instance method itself, `start()` must be invoked on an object (one instantiated by JavaFX, for instance).  The invocation of `getHBox()` without designating a target object is implicitly directed to the same object, as if it were `this.getHBox()`.

> How is `getHBox()` method different from any other method?

It isn't, not in any relevant sense, nor is any of this specific to JavaFX.